# How to generate shopping cart rules programmatically?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, magento-community

I am trying to generate shopping cart rule dynamically for particular product my matching the sku in condition. Rule is getting generated but the condition part is not setting up.
my code :

```
        $data = array(
        'product_ids' => null,
        'name' => sprintf('discount', Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId()),
        'description' => 'Auto generated',
        'is_active' => 1,
        'website_ids' => array(1),
        'customer_group_ids' => array(1),
        'coupon_type' => 2,
        'coupon_code' => Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString(16),
        'uses_per_coupon' => 1,
        'uses_per_customer' => 1,
        'from_date' => null,
        'to_date' => null,
        'sort_order' => null,
        'is_rss' => 1,
        'rule' => array(
        'conditions' => array(
            array(
            'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_found',
            'attribute' => 'sku',
            'operator' => '==',
            'value' => 'tp'
            )
        )
        ),
        'simple_action' => 'by_fixed',
        'discount_amount' => 30,
        'discount_qty' => 0,
        'discount_step' => null,
        'apply_to_shipping' => 0,
        'simple_free_shipping' => 0,
         'stop_rules_processing' => 0,
        'rule' => array(
        'actions' => array(
            array(
            'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_found',
            'attribute' => 'sku',
            'operator' => '==',
            'value' => 'tp'
            )
        )
        ),
        'store_labels' => array('30% Summer discount')
    );
          $model = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
          $data = $this->_filterDates($data, array('from_date', 'to_date'));
          $validateResult = $model->validateData(new Varien_Object($data));
           if ($validateResult == true) {
           if (isset($data['simple_action']) && $data['simple_action'] == 'by_percent'
            && isset($data['discount_amount'])) {
        $data['discount_amount'] = min(100, $data['discount_amount']);
        }
        if (isset($data['rule']['conditions'])) {
        $data['conditions'] = $data['rule']['conditions'];
        }
        if (isset($data['rule']['actions'])) {
        $data['actions'] = $data['rule']['actions'];
        }
        unset($data['rule']);
        $model->loadPost($data);
        $model->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is a script that worked for me](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.com/2010/04/create-bulk-discount-rules.html). The main idea is to build an array that looks exactly as the `$_POST` array does when creating a discount rule using the interface.
If that doesn't work for you, try to create the discount rule in the admin panel, and log the data sent through `$_POST`, then compare it to your data and see the differences.

Comment: Marius, Your script does the exact thing and i also want to thank you for the clear explanation on the link you have given really very clear.

Comment: Seems that you need to set coupon_type when you want to specify a coupon code.

Comment: @DavidManners. You might be right. The script is 4+ years old. Some things have changed since then in the coupon codes section.

Comment: Oddly the system I have is 1.7 like the question

Comment: @DavidManners The script I wrote was for 1.4 I think. I will take a look and do some adjustments. Thanks for the heads up.